# Character set not matching a pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use a regex to match the following:

I want to capture all characters that are followed by a `-` and then a numeric character.

So for example, if the string was `python-proj-5.0` I would want to get `python-proj`.

I tried `[^-0-9]*` but it seems that only matches either a `-` or numeric characters but not a `-` preceded by numeric characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern like this should work:

```
(.*)-[\d.]+
```

This will match any sequence of zero or more characters, captured in group 1, followed by a hyphen, then one or more digits or `.` characters.

Or using a lookahead:

```
.*(?=-[\d.]+)
```

This will match any sequence of zero or more characters which is followed by a hyphen, then one or more digits or `.` characters. The hyphen and the number which follows will not be included in the match.

Comment: The first one doesn't seem to work the way I'd like, but the second one works great. Thank you!

Comment: @n00b for the first pattern, you'll have to extract the first group. Precisely how you do this depends on your platform.